# Angular i18n - Generate single dist folder for all languages instead of one for each language

Tags: javascript, angular, localization, internationalization

I just ran in to this Angular i18n support.

I noticed, on building the app with --localize option,  I get multiple dist folders , one for each language like en-US, fr, de etc;

Is this the standard way.

Can I have only one dist folder, where the locale resource is loaded based on the cookie attribute or localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

While it's suboptimal, I found a solution using a custom build script [based on this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16997#issuecomment-1101508421) on an Angular feature request to do basically what you want.

What you have to do is add a configuration to your `angular.json` like so:

```json
"production-localize": {
   "localize": [
                 "en-US"
               ],
               "deleteOutputPath": false
}
```

Just change the localization code as needed to match your target localization!